# How to add "Check all" checkbox to a <h:dataTable><p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, selectbooleancheckbox

I'm trying to make a form and at the some part of my form I have checkboxes. I'm getting values from java list and setting them directly to the datatable. My datatable looking like:

- tv
- internet
- magazine
- all

So far, it's working perfectly. I want to add some rules to this boxes such as if user put a tick on "all" box other boxes will be ticked too but if user remove one of those ticks except "all" box, the tick of "all" will be removed. I have been searching for this for 2 days, but I have not found any solution. I'd  appreciate if you could describe the approach you managed to solve this.
I'm using Jsf 2.1.19 and PrimeFaces 3.5

My xhtml:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label"><h:outputText value="Şu Kategorilerde Arama Yap"></h:outputText></label>
<div class="controls">
    <h:panelGroup id="categorySelectionPanel">
        <h:dataTable id="tblCategories" value="#{projectBean.categoryList}" var="category">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{category.name}" style="margin-right:10px;" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{category.checked}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

My java class:

```
public class CategoryData {

    private String name;
    private boolean checked;

    public CategoryData() {
    }

    public CategoryData(String name, boolean checked) {
        this.name = name;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just do the check all in jquery $('.someclass ').prop( "checked" )

Comment: You tagged PrimeFaces. Do you really happen to use PrimeFaces? Use `<p:dataTable>` instead then. You will not need any boilerplate code then onwards. There is a facility out of the box that fulfills what you say precisely. Just check out relevant examples on the showcase.